# Recuperar dados geográficos através de uma solicitação HTTP via URL do Google Maps

Tags: java, api, google-maps, url, google

Bom dia galera.

Estou querendo recuperar algumas informações geográficas tendo como parâmetros a latitude e longitude.

Para recuperar tais informações estou tentando fazer uma solicitação via URL através deste link: [Google Maps Geolocation API](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=-15.8040195453225%2C-47.8799401993617).
Ele me retorna um XML onde eu poderei trabalhar em cima do mesmo.

Ao criar este serviço em meu web service, subi para o servidor Weblogic em desenvolvimento (Rodando em Sistema LINUX) e ele me retorna o seguinte erro ao executá-lo:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '502: Bad Gateway' for url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=-15.8040195453225%2C-47.8799401993617'
```

Já tentei de várias maneiras, mas continua dando o mesmo erro. Estou utilizando o código da própria Google para realizar o consumo das informações, segue abaixo:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class GeocodeProcessor {

    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_PREFIX = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";

    private static final int PROXY_PORT                 = 3128;
    private static final String PROXY_HOST              = "vampre.funasa.gov";
    private static final int TIMEOUT                    = 30000;


    public static void main() throws IOException,
            URISyntaxException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

        String urlString = null;

        urlString = GEOCODE_REQUEST_PREFIX + "?latlng=" + URLEncoder.encode("-15.8040195453225,-47.8799401993617", "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(urlString);

        // Convert the string to a URL so we can parse it
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
                PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT));

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

        try {
            // open the connection and get results as InputSource.
            conn.connect();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),
                    "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();
            while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )  {
                ab.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            System.out.println(ab.toString());

        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

Uma ajuda seria extremamente útil agora. Vlw galerinha.

Comment: Por coincidência, estou trabalhando em um projeto que também vai precisar usar essa API. Se eu conseguir resolver, eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Está OK, provavelmente seu proxy ou acesso do servidor em que está acessando à rede externa. Inclua o *stack trace* completo.

Answer (score 2):

O @Bruno está correto!
Dando um **bypass no seu proxy**, o código rodou normalmente!

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Eu fiquei me perguntando, porém, se tinha algo de errado com o código do *proxy* - mas parece que não - instalei um servidor de *proxy* para testar - segue o *log* do programa:

[image: Arquivo de Log do servidor de proxy]

Saída do seu programa:

[image: Resultado da execução do programa]

*O programa de proxy utilizado foi o [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com/).*